# Error on GRUB screen

Tags: grub2, secure-boot

64 bit dual boot system, Win 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04.5

Recently changed GRUB to hide the menu and show a ten second countdown based on the accepted answer to this question: [how can I get my GRUB menu to be hidden, AND have the shift or esc keys show the hidden GRUB menu at boot time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879881/how-can-i-get-my-grub-menu-to-be-hidden-and-have-the-shift-or-esc-keys-show-the)

That works great, but now I am seeing this error during the countdown:

```
Error: Secure Boot forbids loading module from (hd2,gpt4)/boot/grub:x86_x64-efi/true.mod.
```

I checked, and a file `/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/true.mod` does exist, but I have no idea what it does, or what the implications of it not being loaded are.

It does not seem to cause any problem but GRUB errors always concern me.

What is the cause of this error?

Comment: Turn off `secure boot` in your BIOS. Report back. ps: Hi OM! Why would you have a hidden menu with a 10 second countdown vs a menu with a 10 second countdown?

Comment: @heynnema Turning off secure boot got rid of the error.  If you'd like to write this up as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Done! You never did say why you wanted a 10 sec hidden menu vs a 10 sec menu. I'd shave 7 seconds off of my boot time by setting the countdown timer back to 3... :-) Plus... we've got to get you to upgrade those old OS's :-)

Comment: I just love my 14.04 system, it is set up & customized perfectly for me. I'll upgrade to 18.04 next year.

Comment: Windows 10 and Ubuntu 17.04 make a much better pair! Cheers, Al

Comment: I haven't booted the windows side in over a year.  When I need windows, I use a VM

Comment: I do the same thing. However, a "real" Windows boot is required for things like BIOS updates, and USB device firmware updates, etc. I was just hoping get you a little closer to the 21st century... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you have a system that doesn't want to load kernel extensions, or load /boot/grub files, it's a sure bet that `secure boot` needs to be disabled in your BIOS.

`Secure boot` was designed to only allow "signed" software to load, thereby stopping the loading of "unsigned" software, and theoretically potentially harmful software.

It's common in Ubuntu-land to add kernel drivers for wireless cards, and these are typically unsigned also.