# Remove/hide grub menu and decrease boot time

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, 18.04

I have removed Windows partitions in order to completely remove Windows 10 and continue with Ubuntu. However, even after updating grub using `sudo update-grub` it still shows the Windows boot loader. Its output was this:

[image: 1]

I also want to remove the grub menu which shows before booting so that it takes less time to boot up. I tried it with grub customizer. After booting up it takes even more time. I want to know how can I change grub settings so that it takes least amount of time to boot?

Some information about my system is:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- i3-5005u
- 4gb ram

Answer (score 1):

You can use `efibootmgr` to make grub the default boot target to avoid seeing the Windows boot manager. E.g.,

```
$ sudo efibootmgr

BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 10 seconds
BootOrder: 0004,0000,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager
Boot2001* EFI USB Device
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM
Boot2003* EFI Network
```

To make Ubuntu the default, modify the order of the list.

```
$ sudo efibootmgr -o 0,4,2001,2002,2003

BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 10 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0004,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* ubuntu
Boot0003* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager
Boot2001* EFI USB Device
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM
Boot2003* EFI Network
```

Now to reduce the boot timeout in grub, modify the `/etc/default/grub` and set `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to a smaller value.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Modify `GRUB_TIMEOUT=1`

```
sudo update-grub
```

Update: Note that for the boot manager order list, make sure you modify the list you have and not use my example directly. You can also reduce normal efi bootmanager timeout by changing it, e.g.,

```
sudo efibootmgr -t 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this answer as a guideline:

- [Boot-Repair created too many grub menu entries for Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/938633/boot-repair-created-too-many-grub-menu-entries-for-windows/1022700#1022700)

You can change the file `sudo -H gedit /etc/grub.d/25_custom`:

```
───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~/askubuntu$ cat /etc/grub.d/25_custom
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0

───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@alien:~/askubuntu$
```

The extra screen lines were included so you can see there **must be** a third empty line at the bottom of the file.

Grub defaults to a 10 second count down but you can shorten it to about 2 or 3 seconds which gives you enough time to interrupt it. In this example the 10 second countdown has been changed to 5 seconds:

[image: grub boot.gif]

To change the count down time use `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` and find this line:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

Change it to a more reasonable time for you:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
```

Changing it to `0` doesn't work because grub code automatically changes `0` to `10` seconds. For more details see:

- [How can I get my GRUB menu to be hidden, AND have the shift or esc keys show the hidden GRUB menu at boot time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879881/how-can-i-get-my-grub-menu-to-be-hidden-and-have-the-shift-or-esc-keys-show-the/882268?noredirect=1#comment1424271_882268)