# Install Ubuntu but "hide" it in normal boot?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, dell

I have a somewhat old laptop (Dell Inspiron 3541) with Windows 10 installed. Through Live Mode, I've tested that it works with Ubuntu 16.04 (doesn't fully work with 18.04).

After facing some issues with Windows 10, I'd like to install Ubuntu in dual-boot with Windows 10, although I would also like it to not be visible on a normal boot. I'd like to *only* show that Ubuntu is installed when a key is pressed at boot time (like SHIFT to show GRUB).

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: So you want the computer to boot Windows if nothing is pressed? See [How do I change GRUB boot order?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order)

Comment: See my answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/879881/how-can-i-get-my-grub-menu-to-be-hidden-and-have-the-shift-or-esc-keys-show-the Please remember to vote for it if it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @Zackary heynnemas answer is excellent, if I understood correctly you want to press key to boot to Ubuntu otherwise you need Windows to boot directly. In this case you should also set the boot entry priority in `/etc/default/grub` file.