# How to change grub timeout in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Answers to a [very old question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148095/how-do-i-set-the-grub-timeout-and-the-grub-default-boot-entry) suggest to edit

```
/etc/default/grub
```

That file has the following contents:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

The timeout I'm witnessing when booting the system is 10 seconds. According to the configuration file it's 0 seconds though. So, where is the timeout actually defined in Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: All the Ubuntu versions I have installed have had 10 as default & I change to 3. Zero is not recommended as then you may not be able to get into grub to easily resolve a boot issue.

Comment: I don't want to set it to zero. It WAS already at zero. So, where do the 10 seconds I'm seeing come from?

Comment: Every new install has that, not then sure how you got 0. Did you run some software that modifies grub in some way? I would just change back to 10 if that is what you want or whatever number you do want.

Comment: I'd say I didn't do any configuration. But I'll just try to modify the value and see what happens.

Comment: It's really kind of a bug in GRUB. Either set GRUB_TIMEOUT=3, or something less than 10... or if you REALLY want no GRUB menu, let me know, and I'll give you that fix. Are you dual-booting? Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Hello from 2023! Try `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=5` in `/etc/default/grub`, then run `grub-update`, as suggested [below](https://askubuntu.com/a/1393747/681614). Guaranteed to improve your life or your money back!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's kind of a bug in GRUB.

In `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`, here's the code snippet that causes the problem...

```
quick_boot="1"

export TEXTDOMAIN=grub
export TEXTDOMAINDIR="${datarootdir}/locale"

. "$pkgdatadir/grub-mkconfig_lib"

found_other_os=

adjust_timeout () {
  if [ "$quick_boot" = 1 ] && [ "x${found_other_os}" != "x" ]; then
    cat << EOF
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "\${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
EOF
  fi
}
```

To change/fix the 10 second timeout, edit `/etc/grub.d/30_os-prober` with:

`sudo -H gedit /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober`

and either:

1. set `quick_boot="1"` to `quick_boot="0"`
2. set `set timeout=10` to `set timeout=3`

**Note**: or edit `/etc/default/grub` and set GRUB_TIMEOUT=3, or something between 1 and 10.

`sudo update-grub`

**Note**: See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879881/how-can-i-get-my-grub-menu-to-be-hidden-and-have-the-shift-or-esc-keys-show-the) for more details/options.

Comment: So if only Ubuntu or 30_osprober finds no other systems to boot, it uses a quick_boot setting and sets it to 0?  I have never had 0, but always have had multiple boot. I turn off os-prober, usually right after install and use my own 40_custom. But I also change grub timeout to 3.  Historically I have seen many recommendations to never use 0 as then you may not be able to get into grub menu if you need to.

Comment: @oldfred `quick_boot=0` is not the same as `GRUB_TIMEOUT=0`. Revisit the code snippet to fully understand what it's trying to do there.

Comment: That code isn't buggy, it's working as intended. If you open `/etc/defaults/grub` and set `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to anything other than zero, it should work. The reason it's increasing the timeout is to give the user a chance to pick a different OS. That perfectly sensible, and doesn't happen if the user overrides the default value of 0.

Comment: @jpaugh See https://askubuntu.com/questions/879881/how-can-i-get-my-grub-menu-to-be-hidden-and-have-the-shift-or-esc-keys-show-the

Comment: This did not work. Timeout still stuck at ~20 seconds. GRUB_TIMEOUT does nothing to change that.

Comment: @Dave What value did you set in GRUB_TIMEOUT in /etc/default/grub? Try editing the /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober file.

Comment: @heynnema, "3", and I tried editing that other file as well. I made a post about all my troubleshooting here -> https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399557/grub-not-honoring-timeout-value?noredirect=1#comment2426479_1399557

Comment: Does this undocumented OS_Prober rewriting timeout=0 to 10 behavior happen in Upstream Grub, or just in Ubuntu's version?

Answer (score 4):

I am using update-grub 2.02-2ubuntu8.23.

In the file /etc/default/grub I added:

```
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=5
```

The default value was 30 seconds for efi.

When I set the value to 5, it worked and I no longer have to wait 30 seconds if I don't respond to the menu.

It may be that GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT does not apply to all versions of grub. I could not find it documented.  To see if it applies to your version of grub, search /etc/grub.d, which is a set of files for creating the grub configuration:

```
$ grep GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT *
00_header:  set timeout=${GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT:-30}
00_header:  set timeout=${GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT:-30}
```

Comment: In spite of having lived with GRUB since the beginning, its documentation regarding menu modes and timeouts still makes my brain hurt. I don't even _have_ to understand what "recordfail" means, though. I can see the immediate effect of setting `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=5` in `/etc/default/grub` on the timeout values in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` after running `update-grub`, and can confirm this solves the problem. Therefore, all the points to you sir.

Comment: This is the most "correct" answer here, because it doesn't modify files in `/etc/grub.d` that are very likely to be overwritten by a subsequent package update.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand if some cases like EFI Boot active or ex-dual boot when you remove one of these partitions and grub menu continuing to show on startup the correct file to change these situations it's in the boot Grub.
In case this before answer procedures doesn't work, You need to change the line 119 value in "/boot/grub". If you dont no, the command is "sudo gedit /boot/grub".

In the part:

```
  if [ $grub_platform = efi ]; then
  set timeout=00
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
  fi
fi
```

Change the second line `set timeout=30` value `30` to `00`, and save (you need to be a root) and restart.

Comment: /boot/grub is a folder, not a file. You shouldn't edit anything in /boot. Your edit command should be `sudo -H gedit...` or you may end up with a login loop.

Answer (score 0):

For me, i had to:

`chmod uog+w /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

...in order to make it writable, you might want to only hit `o+w` if there are others who use the machine, as the command above gives everyone write access to the file. Then, after hitting
`gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

i changed line 111 (set timeout=-1) to what i wanted:

```
 if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=-1
```

This eliminates the timeout, if you just want a more or less grub time, just change the value to number of seconds without the "-".

Answer (score -1):

Answer from Thiago Lucio did the trick for me.

I have to change

```
"if [ \$grub_platform = efi ]; then
  set timeout=${GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT:-30}"
```

to

```
"if [ $grub_platform = efi ]; then
  set timeout=3"
```

in `/etc/grub.d/00_header`

I use a dual boot with EFI.

Comment: Thiago's answer also worked for me. That said, you should remove the backslash before $grub_platform in your first example and those with less experience should be advised **not** to include quotes lest they're tempted to copy and paste from your examples (or you should consider removing them from your examples.