# grub not honoring timeout value

Tags: grub2, timeout

I have grub working the way I want it on my ubuntu 18.04.
I coppied over /etc/default/grub to my new ubuntu 20.04 box.

Here is the config:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=countdown
GRUB_TIMEOUT=3
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_BACKGROUND="/home/me/Pictures/grub.png"
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768
```

I then performed `sudo update-grub`. This updated the /boot/grub/grub.cfg file. I confirmed timeout settings were set properly in the fil with `cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep -i time`.

I perform a reboot, and the grub menu appears, my image appears, and the countdown starts. 3. 2. 1. Then nothing.... for ~20 seconds. Then grub timesout, and Ubuntu loads.

No matter what I try grub refuses to actually timeout with the value I set. Its stuck on ~20 seconds.

Yes, I read everything [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202309/cannot-get-grub-menu-to-timeout-or-go-away), none of it worked. You can see I tried the `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=$GRUB_TIMEOUT` even `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=3`, nothing works. Even redeployed Ubuntu, same thing.

I noticed this setting appears to change /etc/grub.d/00_header with a conditional for if `if [\$grub_platform = efi ];then`. I am running bios off vmware workstation not uefi. Is this even being honored?

How can I get grub to actually timeout at 3 seconds?

Comment: What happens if you add the line ```if [\$grub_platform = bios ];then``` below the line if ```[\$grub_platform = efi ];then``` (as root) in your grub.cfg and save it. Does it work then ( if not delte the line again ).

Comment: Same problem. I added an `elif` statement after the if, with the same settings. Performed `update-grub`, still need to wait ~20 seconds.

Comment: Do you have a dual boot system? Then the minimum value is 10. If not I don't have a solution for you. Did you ask Dr. Google?

Comment: No, ubuntu is running on Vmware Workstation, not dual boot. 
And yes, I have asked Dr. Google, many times. I think I am annoying Dr. Google with all my questions.

Comment: @Dave Add `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false` in /etc/default/grub, and change `quick_boot="1"` to `quick_boot="0"` in /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober. `sudo update-grub` and `reboot`. Report back.

Comment: i always just comment out or remove "GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE" completely and set the GRUB_TIMEOUT.... With that said, what do you mean by "and ubuntu loads"? Do you mean you see all the output scrolling, or do you mean the login appears? If you are visually watching "3,2,1", that is the GRUB_TIMEOUT that you set and it is honoring it... Are saying that your grub menu actually stays on your screen after the countdown and then __________? The problem in your link says that nothing at all happens after the countdown, seems different.