# How to figure out what is causing GRUB recordfail

Tags: boot, grub2

I had the problem of `GRUB_TIMEOUT="1"` having no effect. Just like in these questions [1](https://askubuntu.com/q/202309/307091) [2](https://askubuntu.com/q/694730/307091) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57993420/4335271). Setting `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT="1"` accomplished what I needed. [A related article](https://www.tomica.net/blog/2019/02/remove-efi-grub-timeout). But I am not certain if this is the (GRUB-designer-)intended solution to my problem. Should I instead be fixing whatever is causing the recordfail to trigger in the first place?

## How do I figure out what is causing recordfail to be triggered?

#### Observations/attempts:

- I tried running both `grub-editenv create` and `sudo grub-editenv - unset recordfail`. Followed by `sudo update-grub`. No visible results.
- In the file `/etc/grub.d/00_header` in the function `make_timeout()` there are the following lines:

```
if [ "\${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=${GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT:-30}
```

```
if [ "$recordfail_broken" = 1 ]; then
  cat << EOF
if [ \$grub_platform = efi ]; then
  set timeout=${GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT:-30}
  if [ x\$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
  fi
fi
EOF
fi
```

(I don't understand the syntax in the second excerpt and why there is an if-clause inside an if-clause.)

I changed the timeout in the second excerpt from `30` to `50` and, after `sudo update-grub` and a restart, observed that the GRUB timeout at boot was indeed 50 seconds.

- I also verified that in the grub console at boot `echo $grub_platform` yields `efi`.

#### Extra info:

Current `/etc/default/grub` (the colors at the end don't work):

```bsh
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT="0"
#GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE="hidden"
GRUB_TIMEOUT=2
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1 sysrq_always_enabled=1"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="2"
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER="true"
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT="1"

export GRUB_COLOR_NORMAL="green/black"
export GRUB_COLOR_HIGHLIGHT="light-green/black"
```

I think my system uses UEFI (laptop from 2017 maybe), but I'm planning to switch my boot to legacy (BIOS?) mode soonish (due to a kernel parameter needed for an SSD to boot).

I'm using LVM, but not encryption. `/boot` is on ext4 under LVM.

Kubuntu 18.04

Comment: What is the file system on your /boot? Are you using LVM or encryption?

Comment: Once I noticed that plugged-in jack of headphone hanged the grub.

Comment: This is by design.

Comment: Thanks! Do I understand correctly that the forced 30 second timeout is a workaround to avoid problems of EFI + boot on LVM not showing grub menu correctly (sometimes? always?) if the menu is hidden (due to inability to detect key presses of shift and esc)? And setting `GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT` is a workaround to this safety protection?

Comment: You got it exactly. I argued that I can alway get into grub menu, but the maintainers left it this way, but added the `RECORDFAIL` option for brave people.)) In case you really can't get into grub, which is unlikely, you can always boot from a LiveUSB and revert the setting back.

Comment: If a boot fails, grub can't record it to LVM. So there is a possibility that you are unable to get to grub menu to boot in safe mode or another kernel. That's the main reason.